Who originated the paged database structure with extents?
An old (late 1970s) DBM library I'm reverse-engineering has the following page structure (genericized):



Contents
Comment




Page ID
DB name + page number in the DB


Usage
Extent count in the pageThe last unused word in the page


Extent handles
Each handle contains:handle number (non-zero) within the pagestarting location of extent contents within the pageextent lengthnext extent (page#, handle#) within the datum, or 0 if it is the last


Free space
From the first word after extent handles up to the last unused word


Extent contents
The first (or the only) extent of a datum has a header mentioning its total length



As far as I remember, I once was told that storing data at the bottom of pages, and handles - at the top of pages of databases, so that defragmenting data is a straightforward operation, is a common technique.
Is it known who is the inventor of it, and does that data structure have a name?

Can't put a finger on, but it reminds me of the base of a linked list datastructure/database I once had to convert. But unlike above hinted, the linked lists didn't end with an EOF marker, but kinked back to a higher level entry. Like an order linking to it's items chain which at the end linked back to the order. No idea what system that originated.

@Raffzahn I believe that you're thinking about the lists of b-tree nodes, rather than the data blocks.

Just a comment, no graspable knowledge, even less authority. It's been a small side project a good 45 years ago, so details are blurry. All I had was binary access to a disk mounted in a drive with zero information. Above reminded me of digging thru that unusual (IMHO) structure.

VAX DBMS was a database system built according to the CODASYL framework.  It organized the database files into pages, and had some mechanisms for resolving dtabase links into file (within database), page (within file) and line (within page).  An index at the start ofeach page could translate line number into a pair of numbers for byte offset and byte count.
VAX DBMS used a code base called KODA for low level database operations.
When DEC decided to build a relational database,  they reused the KODA code base, adapting it for the kind of keyed reference that is typical of the relational approach.  This became RDB/VMS.  This was sold to Oracle Corp. in 1994, which rebranded it Oracle Rdb.
I don't know where the originators of KODA got their ideas for data structures inside database pages.
Edit for full disclosure: I never did learn VAX DBMS, or even how to build a CODASYL database.  I took one look at CODASYL and said "there's got to be a better way".  When I revisited databases a few years later, there was a better way.  It was relational.
You didn't have to be as smart as Codd to learn relational.  If you could learn Datatrieve, and you could appreciate what Codd was trying to achieve,  then you could learn relational.

So, you're basically saying that this structure was defined by the CODASYL committee?

CODASYL started with Charles Bachman's system as a start. There were a number of databases that used this type of structure. I worked with IDMS back in the day but that had an earlier start as something from B.F. Goodrich. The page structure evolved over time and my memory of the specifics is lost to time. What's not lost, though, is the reliance we had on the structure, or knowledge of the structure, for tuning the database for performance.

@DaveD It is plausible that it was Charles Bachman who invented it, but how do we ascertain that?

AFAIK,  KODA was working at a different level of abstraction than the CODASYL committe was concerned with.  What made KODA worth reusing was how clean the layers of abstraction worked with each other.  This means that, when you cut over to relational, there was a  relatively small amount of baggage that came over with it.  But this impression of mine is not base don staring at the code.  It's based on the commentries made by those who did stare at the code.

When I studied Rdb internals, I did learn a certain amount about the low level data structures that dealt with issues that the database designer didn't have to think about.
